# Update an envelope property to signify It has been downloaded

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We want to update an envelope property to signify It has been downloaded by our application at least once before. What is the best practice for that? I tried to use a custom field for that purpose but since custom fields can't be updated once the envelopes are completed is not a feasible option, is there a way to add a custom status to the envelopes?
Another option is to store the last date we downloaded envelopes and start downloading from that date the next time, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out.

When do you need to download the document exactly? I presume you only want to download the documents when the envelope is complete (and you're looking to set a flag somewhere to indicate that documents are downloaded).

In that case, I would suggest you look into DocuSign connect (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/)

When the completed event comes in, you can go ahead and download the documents. You don't need to set a flag anywhere as the event is fired only once when the envelope is complete.

If flagging the download is a strict requirement for some reason, then you can look into setting up DocuSign Connect with a queueing system such as Azure service bus or other cloud provider equivalents ( https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-azure). In this case, if the queue pointer is pointing to the next completion event where documents need to be download. Anything prior is already downloaded.